# How can I list temporary tables/views in SQLite?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have a function which attempts to drop a view and rebuild it whenever a new database is attached to the connection. The problem (well, more of an annoyance) is that the first time it tries to drop a non existent view. Since there is a permanent table with the same name as the view I get the sqlite error: `use DROP TABLE to delete table Albums`. Therefore, I would like to query the database to check if the view exists before attempting to drop it.

Note: the current query already uses `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS` and that does not solve the problem. Also, I checked `sqlite_master` and there doesnt appear to be any references to temporary tables/views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` and `temp` databases are distinct, so you can just use the database name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Albums(x);
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW Albums AS SELECT * FROM Albums;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS temp.Albums;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS temp.Albums;
```

Temporary objects [are managed in `sqlite_temp_master`](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7).